# Update value in mysql table when select box onchange

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database

I have a html table that contains values in my mysql db table. Client ask for a front-end editing of data in my html table. So i make td transform to selection box when click, where the user will choose X and O remarks.

this is my script :

```
 $(document).on('click', 'td', function() { ////---make td transform to dropdown list box when click---///
          if($(this).find('select').length == 0) {
              $(this).empty();  //clears out current text in the table
              $(this).append('<select onchange="myFunction()" id="Remarks" name="Remarks"><option value=""></option><option <?php if ($Remarks=='X') echo 'selected';?> value="X" style="font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;">X<option style="font-size:20px;color:green;font-weight:bold;" <?php if ($Remarks=='O') echo 'selected';?> value="O">O</select>');
          }
    });


    $(document).on('focusout', 'td select', function(){ 
        var myValue = $(this).val();
        var $parent = $(this).parent();
        $(this).remove();
        $parent.append(myValue);        
    });
```

What I Need is to make update for the value of td based on what the user choose from the selection box.

This is what I have tried : Making an onchange for the selection box

```
function myFunction(){
        var emp_name = document.getElementById('employeeName').value;
        var r = document.getElementById('Remarks').value;
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'update_data.php',
                    data: {
                        'employeeName' :emp_name,
                        'DAY1' : r
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        $("#content").html(data)
                        $(".loader").fadeOut("veryslow");               
                        $("#content").hide().fadeIn(500)  
                        //alert(r); 
                        //alert(emp_name);
                    },
                    error:function(data){
                        alert('Failed');
                    }
                })

    };
```

and this is my update_data.php :

```
<?php
    $employeeName = $_REQUEST["employeeName"];
    $Remarks = $_REQUEST["Remarks"];
    //$id = $_REQUEST["id"];

    try {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost:***;dbname=******;', '*****', '*****' );
        $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        $pdo->query( 'SET NAMES UTF8' );
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare(
            "UPDATE `mbwa`
            SET
                `DAY1` = :Remarks
            WHERE
                `employeeName` = :employeeName
            "
        );
        $stmt->bindValue(':employeeName',$employeeName,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':Remarks',$Remarks,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        //$stmt->bindValue(':id',$id,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        header('location:./');
    } catch ( PDOException $e ) {
        var_dump( $e->getMessage() );   
    }

    $pdo = null;
    ?>
```

it updates the database but it gives a value of null in value of the td that i make change. I think it doesn't get the value of ':Remarks' in my update query.

any help?

Comment: `$_REQUEST["Remarks"];` should be `$_REQUEST["DAY1"];` (check the ajax params sended!)

Comment: It doesn't update! I think $_REQUEST["Remarks"];  is right no need to make request for the column DAY1. I've tried that before.

Comment: I'm sure that if your ajax says  `data: { 'employeeName' :emp_name,'DAY1' : r}`, your php should `$_REQUEST` for `employeeName` and `DAY1`. So, there's another error but you should first solve this.

Comment: I've tried to put $_REQUEST for 'DAY1' and also bindValue. It gives me this error string(100) "SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens"

Comment: Edit the question and make the changes. Probably the `var r = document.getElementById('Remarks').value;` gives you a array. Try to console log empoyeeName and **r** before ajax.

Comment: I think the issue is it doesn't retain the value of the selection box. So the query throws a null value. Maybe I need some script in here : $(document).on('focusout', 'td select', function(){     any idea?

Comment: Make a console log instead the ajax, and check what's `r` getting.

Comment: I tried to alert(r); and it shows the value that i selected in selection box. So it gets the value.

Comment: `$_REQUEST["Remarks"];` should be `$_REQUEST["DAY1"];` change it please. and make the php return the `$stmt` query to see what wrong-

Comment: Ok now I got it. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: Glad to help!...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `$_REQUEST["Remarks"];` should be `$_REQUEST["DAY1"];`

Because your `data` in Ajax are sended like this:

```
data: {
       'employeeName' :emp_name,
       'DAY1' : r
},
```

So, in the **PHP** you have to change it to this:

```
$employeeName = $_REQUEST["employeeName"];
$Remarks = $_REQUEST["DAY1"];
```